# QProcess returning an exit code of 0

Tags: c++, bash, qt

I'm using QProcess to run a ping to a few hosts. When I use QProcess with the command as "ping -c 1 -W 1 hostname" the exit code being returned is always 0 regardless if the ping is successful or not. I have tested hosts that are offline in the terminal and the exit code is as expected. Assume hostname is an actual host that is offline.
This is the code snippet that includes QProcess:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString cmd("ping -c 1- W 1 hostname");
process->start(cmd);
std::cout << process->exitCode() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QProcess::exitCode()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitCode) says:

> Returns the exit code of the *last* process that finished.

So, you need to wait for the process ([`QProcess::waitForFinished`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished)) to exit before checking its exit code.

**Example:**

```
if ( !process->waitForFinished( -1 ) )
{
    qWarning() << "Error:" << process->errorString();
    return;
}

qDebug() << "Exit code:" << process->exitCode();
```